# Linq To XML: Find XElement by name in XML and get parent attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<applications>
    <category cat="Player">
        <app>
            <name>4Media Blu Ray Creator</name>
        </app>
    </category>
    <category cat="Burning">
        <app>
            <name>Nero Micro</name>
        </app>
</category>
</applications>
```

Now I want to search in **app** names and return list of XApplications that contains category names(parent cat attribute).

this is my **XApplication**  class:

```
class XApplication
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Category { set; get; }

    public XApplication(string name, string category)
    {
        Name = name;
        Category = category;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my way to do that:

```
XApplication[] appList = (from xapp in applicationXml.Elements("category").Elements("app")
                           where xapp.Element("name").Value.ToLower().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower())
                           select new XApplication
                           {
                                Name = xapp.Element("name").Value,
                                Category = xapp.Parent.Attribute("cat").Value

                           }).ToArray();
```